# Xcode Activity Log Complete error

Tags: objective-c, xcode7

1. My code was working yesterday. After I restart my macbook, now it keep showing me Activity Log Complete error. How can I prevent this from happen again?

[image]

Comment: Please add a more complete error log. This is a general error. Help us help you.

Comment: @Chiyang did this problem solved ever?

Answer (score 4):

Am also done the same mistakes in 2times,one time i have deleted the .h and .m files so at that time it was happened,and another time is 
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *DataArray,that has changed extern NSArray *DataArray.Then i have to cleared the Extern keyword it will changed.

Comment: The problem was with my array that it initialised and used wrongly!